# Find start and end date of when value exceeds a certain threshold for at least X time periods

Tags: r, date, threshold

I have three columns, one of which contains a statistic, the other a critical value, and the final one the date. I would like to know how to find the start and end date when the threshold of the critical value is exceeded for at least n periods. A simple example of the data is as follows:

```
Date        Statistic  Critical Value
2003-01-01  1.1        0.80
2003-01-08  1.5        0.90
2003-01-15  2.1        0.91
2003-01-22  0.5        0.95
2003-01-29  1.4        0.98
2003-02-05  1.3        1.00
2003-02-12  0.8        1.10
```

I would expect the output with a minimum period of 3 to be:

```
Start      End
2003-01-01 2003-01-15
```

However if the minimum period was 2 rather than 3 I would expect:

```
Start      End
2003-01-01 2003-01-15
2003-01-29 2003-02-05
```

Comment: Could you post the expected output for this example?

Comment: Thanks for your response I have modified the question to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very self explanatory solution with `data.table` would be:
(There might be more compact solutions)

```
require(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[,exceeds:=Statistic>CriticalValue]
DT[,mydiff := c(0,diff(exceeds))]
DT[mydiff<0, mydiff := 0]
DT[,run := cumsum(mydiff)]
DT[c(exceeds),.(start=Date[1], end = Date[.N], length = .N), by=run]
```

Results in:

```
   run      start        end length
1:   0 2003-01-01 2003-01-15      3
2:   1 2003-01-29 2003-02-05      2
```

So if you only want runs with `length>2` use

```
DT_agg <- DT[c(exceeds),.(start=Date[1], end = Date[.N], length = .N), by=run]
DT_agg[length>2]

   run      start        end length
1:   0 2003-01-01 2003-01-15      3
```